# Weak equality in angular select

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I'm trying to build an angular app with a parse.com backend.  In the app, a Student can be placed into one of many Classrooms.  I have a view that shows a row for each student, and in each row a `<select>` whose options are classrooms to which the student can be assigned.  I am able to initially assign and save the pointer from student->classroom.

The controller gets things going like this:

```
Student.withGrade($scope.grade).then(function(students) {
    // this eagerly fetches each student's assigned classroom
    $scope.students = students;
});

Classroom.withGrade($scope.grade).then(function(classrooms) {
    $scope.classrooms = classrooms;
});
```

And the classroom selector looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="classroom" ng-model="student.classroom"
    ng-options="classroom.name for classroom in classrooms"></select>
```

The problem is, if I reload the page, even though some students have their classroom pointers initialized, the classroom select for those rows does not show that classroom (it appears uninitialized).

I think the reason is that even though the student's classroom object is *equivalent* to one of the classrooms in scope, they are retrieved by different fetches, so they are not *equal* as far as the `<select>` is concerned.

Is there a way to make the select test equivalence (say, like classroom.id) rather than equality?

I think one way to solve this is wait for both queries to finish, and then run through the students and replace their classroom pointer with a pointer to the equivalent fetched classroom, but that seems crazy.  (I still need it to select the whole classroom object into `student.classroom` because that's what parse needs in order to properly save the student).

**EDIT** - Just confirmed that the problem is select equality.  This fixes the problem, but there must be a way to get the select to make the equivalence test (`.id == c.id`)

```
Student.withGrade($scope.grade).then(function(students) {
    // this eagerly fetches each student's assigned classroom
    $scope.students = students;
    return Classroom.withGrade($scope.grade);
}).then(function(classrooms) {
    $scope.classrooms = classrooms;

     // yuck - resolve the students' classroom pointers so the selectors will work
    _.each($scope.students, function(student) {            
        if (student.classroom) {
            student.classroom = _.find(classrooms, function(c) {
                return student.classroom.id == c.id;
            });
        }
    });
});
```